# Playback open error: -16,Device or resource busy

Tags: linux, gstreamer, alsa

I am trying alsa speaker-test utility after playing a .mp3 file using gst-play-1.0 in my customized Linux Os.but the speaker-test utility is unable to produce the sound over any channel and its producing a following error message given below.

speaker-test -p 1000 -t wav -c 6 -s 6

speaker-test 1.2.1

Playback device is default
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 6 channels
WAV file(s)
Playback open error: -16,Device or resource busy.

Based on my analysis, I found that the audio card/device "/dev/snd/pcmC0D0p" was used by gst-play-1.0 and its is not released even after gst-play-1.0 command execution.

I could see the result of lsof /dev/snd/* as

root   29u   CHR 116,16      0t0 13359 /dev/snd/pcmC0D0p

Is anyone know how to release this resource so that I can use it for speaker-test ?

Answer (score 0):

Your device is busy and your `lsof` shows about a process using the device, just that doesn't seems to indicate the exact command where this comes. Probably because of the CoreUtils your custom Linux uses for these tools, in this case `lsof`. Otherwise you will have a little more info, some output similar to this one:

```bash
$ lsof /dev/video*
COMMAND     PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
gst-launc 20425  my-user   5u   CHR   81,0      0t0  606 /dev/video0
```

As your `lsof` seems to indicate that someone is using that device, let's suppose it is an instance of `speaker-test`. So that you can just do a process search and kill that process to free the device; rerun `lsof` and see if the device is now available. If it is try again with your sound test!

```bash
ps aux | grep speaker

kill -9 <PID for Speaker>
lsof /dev/snd/*
```

Comment: After killing 13359,  not producing any result for lsof /dev/snd/*. Both "/dev/snd/controlC0" and "/dev/snd/pcmC0D0p" process are killed. Now the speaker-test works as expected but the gst-play-1.0 command not working, its not able to play the audio file. I need both commands should work one after another. Could you please help on this ?

Comment: What does it shows, what is the command for gst-play-1.0?